# Trying to connect to Azure Analysis Services through SSMS

Tags: ssms, azure-analysis-services

I've been trying to connect to AZure analysis services through SSMS by using the server name found in the portal. However 2 things are strange: in SSMS the Windows authentication is grayed out and also it is causing me the error as below. Any guidance please?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the latest ssms version (17.x). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms
2. Download and install the latest client libraries (Adomd, MSOLAP, ADO).

Here is the links for detailed information.

1. Connect SSMS to Azure Analysis services - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage
2. Client libraries - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-connect

Answer (score 1):

Server name must include asazure scheme ie

"asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/..."

Answer (score 1):

What version of SSMS Are you using?

We had many issues until we upgraded [SSMS to the RC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-release-candidate).

If you use SQL Server Data Tools, update that [to the RC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-release-candidate) too.